# Is it possible to configure toolbar/panels width and height in visual studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

The vertical column that contains the code line number is VS2019 is too wide. Is there a way to narrow it down? Also toolbars is too height. In each new version there is less and less coding space. Maybe somebody knows the way to rid/decrease using space of some panels?

[image: width sample]

I prefer just remove that panels, but don't know how ):

[image: Bottom panels not helpful]

Too much free space here

[image: Top toolbars is too height]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if customizing your IDE and features within from a few ways mentioned in the following docs help you out in utilizing the IDE space better, if not in the exact same way as asked:

- Customizing window layouts in VS 2019: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customizing-window-layouts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019
- How to: Customize menus and toolbars in VS 2019: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-customize-menus-and-toolbars-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

If this doesn't help solve the purpose, please feel free to provide feedback or submit a suggestion here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html